# fadeIn effect only flashes

Tags: jquery, css, fadein

I'm trying to add a fadein to my jquery string so the div fades in when clicked. I'm only gettng a flash and then no fade. I'm still a beginner with jquery. Does this seem like it should work?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Thumb1").click(function() {
        $("#hidden").html('<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/38366163" width="508" height="286" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>').hide().fadeIn('2000');
        $("#leftsidePlayer").text("hey there new text!");
    });
});​    ​
```

I've also tried with `.hide` and using `disply: none` in my CSS with same affect.

Comment: Where is your HTML? Is the function executed at all? Can you verify this? otherwise try `$("#Thumb1").bind('click', function(){ ... });`

Comment: @Smamatti. `.click === .bind('click')` his problem is the string duration, it should be a number.(or string with `'slow'\'fast'`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The duration should be a number not a string:

```
$("#hidden").hide()
            .html('<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/38366163" width="508" height="286" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>')
            .fadeIn(2000); // <==== Not fadeIn('2000')
```

[**JSFidde DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HxP3W/)

> Durations are given in milliseconds; higher values indicate slower animations, not faster ones. The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600 milliseconds, respectively. If any other string is supplied, or if the duration parameter is omitted, the default duration of 400 milliseconds is used.

Side note, it will be better to hide the element then append it the `<iframe>` and after all of that is done, fade the container in.

Comment: Acutally I'm still seeing a flash before the fadeIn effect. I've added some more code so that the player loads the 1st Thumbnail on page load. Could thei be causing the problem? see here http://www.doublezerofilms.com/doublezero-template-webSamples.html

Comment: @Greg. I guess it's because it takes time to load the `<iframe>` try use setTimeout of 4 seconds then do the fadeIn. Another good option is move the fade to onload not onDOM ready. Good luck!